# Words from HEX alphabet

Tags: naming, memory-address, hex

I'm looking for words that can be created from hex alphabet `[0-9a-f]+`
like `C0FFEE, DEFACED`
We also can use `lisoz`, where `1=l,i; 5=s; 2=z; 0=o` etc.
It can be used in memory addressing or IPv6 address, so it will be funny and much easier to remember.

There is nice list here: http://www.nsftools.com/tips/HexWords.htm
but I'm sure we can think out something that is not there or invent new words :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has an article on the more popular ones:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak

Answer (score 7):

```
$ grep "^[0-9a-flo]*$" /usr/share/dict/words |
  tr lo 10 | awk '{print length, $0}' |
  sort -n | cut -f2- -d' ' | tail -n5

c0ffee1eaf
defaceab1e
effaceab1e
f1eeceab1e
c01db100ded
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a handful.

```
0ff1ce
decaf
ed1f1ce
```

There are well over a thousand valid 3-or-more-letter words, but many of them are barely recognisable, such as 50c1a112ab1e (socializable). Sticking to just 0=o, things are much cleaner. Here are some highlights:

```
accede
beaded
bedded
b0bbed
c0bbed
c0ffee
decade
dec0de
deface
d0bbed
d0decade
d00dad
efface
facade
```